# Using Word Find/Replace Tool to Highlight

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I want to highlight the following links using Word find/replace tool:

asdasdsa.com/192jd92d2

asdasdsa.com/192jd92d223232

asdasdsa.com/192jd92d24323f23f32f

Is there a way I can get Word to highlight each of those using one formula?

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the `Use wildcards` feature of Word.

On the Find and Replace dialog, click `More` and enable `Use wildcards`.

Within the `Find what:` field, include a `*` to represent any number of characters and `^13` to indicate a linebreak.

Click in the `Replace with:` field. Then select `Format` | `Highlight`.

[image]

Any line that contains `asdasdsa.com` will be highlighted starting with `asdasdsa.com` to the end of the line.

Comment: It worked! Can you explain what means a linebreak?

Comment: I mean why did you use 13? Can you elaborate?

Comment: A linebreak is inserted when you press the Enter key. If you are showing formatting marks in Word, you would see the paragraph symbol. `^13` is just the symbol representing the linebreak character. ASCII decimal code 13 is the character code for carriage return, which is probably why `^13` was chosen.